# Pass params to knockout components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have some issues passing variables to  knockout components as parameters.

In the documentation on knockoutjs.com it tells that this should work:

```
<special-offer params='productName: someProduct.name'></special-offer>
```

but i cant seem to get it working out .
I do however get the param sent over if it isnt a variable, works with numbers.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure `someProduct` is available within context of the component
  and that the `name` property is an observable.
- If the `name` property
  is a function you may also want to try `someProduct.name()`

[Example component implementation taken from Knockout's website](https://jsfiddle.net/jessejjohnson/msdcwcwr/)

Comment: Updated linked example